# Letter spacing with unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math, letterspacing

As this example shows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[LetterSpace=20]{Junicode}
\setmathfont[Script=Latin,LetterSpace=20]{Junicode}

\begin{document}
xy = z\par
$xy = z$
\end{document}
```

The LetterSpace option is not applied to the math font. Can it be made to?

---

PS (in response to comments): The above is just to isolate the problem. I use

```
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}
\setmathfont[
 range={"0370-"03FF,   % greek
 "0000-"007F},         % ascii range
 Numbers=Lowercase]
 {Junicode}
```

I am aware that Junicode is not a math font, but I still want to know how to control the spacing, and I don't want a special font for maths. (And I would præfer not to have to put an explicit kerning command between all adjacent variables.)

Comment: Since Junicode is not a math font…

Comment: as [I said before](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290555/lualatex-and-mathspec#comment703099_290555) You need a math font to set up the math parameters and then you can specify that some letters come from a different font if you need that.

Comment: For one-off, use the spacing commands `\,` and so on

Comment: if you want people to help why insist on using obsolete forms that make it hard even for a native speaker to read your question?  `præfer `  `æquivalent` etc.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I find it difficult to believe that anyone finds it hard to read something where occationally there is an æ for e.

Comment: I don't see why you find that difficult at all. You insist on using unreadable forms that I have never seen (but the internet does confirm existed in previous centuries) and don't provide a useable example that demonstrates the problem.  It seems that you have not put any serious effort into producing a question that anyone can answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, you mean you had to google præfer to discover that (by) it (I) meant prefer?

Comment: I could guess but I had to google to see if it had ever been a word in English, which it has not been for several hundred years it seems. But this is an international forum where English is not the first language of most users and a major aim of the site is to facilitate searching in English using such forms (especially in titles) is not particularly helpful. Since you rolled back the perfectly reasonable edits made to your previous question, no point in editing this one so voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, all right, close it because a man searching for 'prefer' would not find it.

Comment: No, I voted to close  because no example code that may be run to demonstrate the problem is provided, and because the text is deliberately obfuscated.

Comment: The letterspace works with lualatex but not with xelatex. Imho the implementation in xelatex is so that it can't work in math see.e.g. http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/xetex/2009-January/011889.html.